# Is this a bug in PHP's DOMDocument Library?

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm trying to parse some HTML with PHP, but there is an error. Here is the relevant code, which can be run on the command line (`$ php script.php`).

```
<?php
function images_to_links($text)
{
    $dom = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

    // Load the document, hiding and then restoring error setting
    $internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($text, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);

    // Extract images from the dom
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    // Other processing code removed for this example 

    $cleaned_html = $dom->saveHTML();
    return $cleaned_html;
}

$some_text = <<<EOD
<blockquote>asdf</blockquote>
<a href="http://example.com/">click here</a>
<br />
<p><a href="http://example.com/">another link</a></p>
EOD;

print images_to_links($some_text);
```

Expected output:

```
<blockquote>asdf</blockquote>
<a href="http://example.com/">click here</a>
<br />
<p><a href="http://example.com/">another link</a></p>
```

Actual output -- notice how the `blockquote` has wrapped around the other elements:

```
<blockquote>asdf<a href="http://example.com/">click here</a><br><p><a href="http://example.com/">another link</a></p></blockquote>
```

Is there an error in my code or is this a bug with domdocument?

Comment: Seems to be something to do with `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED`, though no idea why...

Comment: I wouldn't consider it a bug.  My assumption is that DOMDocument, like most DOM utilities, expects everything to be nested under a single tag like `<html>`.

Comment: Hmm.. that would make sense. Stretching the first tag to wrap around everything doesn't make sense though. I will pre-wrap it in a `<div>`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LibXML requires a root node, so interprets the first element it finds as the root node (ignoring its closing tag).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't consider it a bug. My assumption is that DOMDocument, like most DOM utilities, expects everything to be nested under a single tag like `<html>`.

By using the `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` flag, you're telling DOMDocument to forgo the step it usually takes with partial HTML by wrapping it in `<html><body>` tags.

http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php